# Evaluating Expression in Function call

Tags: ember.js, mustache, handlebars.js

I have this function call that makes a checkbox

```
{{checkbox "checkbox_{{id}}" }}
```

but as you might have guessed, the result I get, is

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_{{id}}" id="checkbox_{{id}}">
```

Im looking for it to evaluate the {{id}} in the function call.

Comment: Do you have a helper function for the "checkbox" key?  Is that what your block is about?  If so, you need to pass it arguments and let it form the entire return HTML.  You can't combine strings before sending as an argument.  Can you show us the code for the helper?  For example, maybe you should be using `{{checkbox "checkbox_" id}}` and let your helper combine the two when generating the id.

Comment: @jfriend00 i was given the code and have no idea where the helper is (it's a huge project). Though, I guess I can just manually create the checkbox...

Comment: Well then, if the existing helper function only takes a single string and you can't change it, then as far as I know, you can't do what you want.  The design of handlebars would be to fix/change the helper function to accept the two pieces of the id and have the helper function put them together or to just put this in your template: `<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_{{id}}" id="checkbox_{{id}}">` and let it just fill in the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Just pass the id

Pass in `id` and have the helper append it to the `name` and `id` attributes with whatever prefix you want.

**Template**

```
{{{checkbox id}}}
```

**Helper**

```
// Expression Helper
Handlebars.registerHelper('checkbox', function (id) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_' + id + '" id="checkbox_' + id + '">';
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfullam/390t5cnh/

---

**UPDATE:**
It's worth noting that Handlebars will not evaluate a mustache inside of a mustache. But...

### Subexpressions

> Handlebars offers support for subexpressions, which allows you to
>   invoke multiple helpers within a single mustache, and pass in the
>   results of inner helper invocations as arguments to outer helpers.
>   Subexpressions are delimited by parentheses.

```
{{{checkbox (myOtherHelper id)}}}
```

### Multiple arguments

You may also pass in multiple arguments to a single helper:

**Template**

```
{{{checkbox "checkbox_" id}}}
```

**Helper**

```
// Expression Helper
Handlebars.registerHelper('checkbox', function (prefix, id) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" name="' + prefix + id + '" id="' + prefix + id + '">';
});
```

Comment: I ended up using the subexpressions. I made a helper that concatted the arguments and passed them to the checkbox helper. Thanks!